# ASP.NET - changes will not take effect until IISExpress is restarted

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I'm developing an ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio.

I'm finding that whenever I make a change to the website whilst IISExpress is running, I have to restart IISExpress before any of the changes become live on my dev machine.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there some kind of caching turned on which is causing this?

Comment: Try clear the browser caching. Ctrl + F5 if you use Chrome. Have you try to run Visual Studio with Administrator's rights? Try close and open VS

Comment: I wish it was something as simple as that! Unfortunately that's not the issue here. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl + F5 whenever refreshing the page to get the new content instead of just F5 or browsers refresh button. If the issue persists, clear Cache, restart VS and if still persists restart your computer.